# Stop thread with while running

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm making a keylog and the code of keylog is in a class extends Thread. And I put a boolean running like variable and I have this code :

```
public void run() {
    while(running)
        try {
            Config conf = new Config();
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("keylog/output-file.txt")));

            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();

            GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(new Keylog(conf));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException | NativeHookException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

And i have another void method to stop thread

```
void stopKeylog() {
    running=false;
}
```

But when, I stop thread, I will see the output txt file and is with bugs.
And when I remove the `while(running)` the output, the works perfectly.

Comment: I guess you should define your running variable with volatile modifier

Comment: Are you sure you want all that code inside the loop?  You don't want to create a new `new Config()` every time.

Comment: Afaik you're adding an endless number of `Keylog(conf)` instances. Please explain what your code does.

Comment: @nikolayYashchenko I have private boolean running;

Comment: @karlRichter my code saves all key pressed in a txt file
if i remove while running, works
but when I put the while, the txt file, mkaes a while iin keys too
so stay more of less like:
keyPrssed:a
keyPrssed:a
keyPrssed:a
keyPrssed:a

Comment: So if it works, why adding the while loop?

Comment: @TozéFicticio it doesn't matter if it's private or not. Try to add volatile, so that another thread will see any changes ASAP

Comment: @didierc because, i want to add while loop, because when i'm typing saves in txt files, and when I stop the thread, the running goes to false, and stop writting to txt file

Comment: @nikolayyashchenko when I change to volatile, the txt file don't capture anything

Answer (score 0):

Few quick inputs if it helps:
1. Make running as volatile
2. Close the PrintStream (not sure if it would help)

Comment: when i put volatile the file txt don't capture the key pressed